# How to pass a sub protocol type where a super protocol type is expected in Swift? (Think passing subclass type for baseclass type but for protocols)

Tags: swift, inheritance, swift-protocols, protocol-inheritance

I am stuck on a protocol inheritance problem in Swift. I am trying to construct an API that accepts an array of Protocol Types X. Consumers of this API should be able to then pass in any type of protocol type X OR any sub protocol type X' that inherits from protocol X. It seems this can-not be achieved in Swift without some form of explicitly casting the Protocol type X' back to Protocol type X. Why is this the case? I dont see this behavior with Class Types (I suspect maybe its because the inheritance works markedly differently).

This is my code:

```
public protocol InjectableService
{}

public protocol ClientDependency
{
    func serviceDependencies() -> [InjectableService.Type]
    func injectDependencies(dependencies: [InjectableService])
}



public protocol TouchIdServiceInterface : InjectableService
{
    func biometricAuthenticate() -> Void
}

public protocol PasswordServiceInterface : InjectableService
{
    func passwordAuthenticate() -> Void
}

public class LoginController : ClientDependency
{
    private var services: [InjectableService]!

    public func injectDependencies(dependencies: [InjectableService]) {
        services = dependencies
    }

    public func serviceDependencies() -> [InjectableService.Type] {
        return [TouchIdServiceInterface.self as! InjectableService.Type , PasswordServiceInterface.self as! InjectableService.Type]
    }


}
```

As you can see from above in the function serviceDependencies() I have to do this weird casting of the sub protocol type back to its super protocol type. If I remove the cast I get a compiler warning explicitly asking me to do that.

Is there any way to avoid this? I like that with class types it can figure it out for you. I really want to avoid this casting problem because its going to make using the API extremely clunky. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting. Been playing for a few minutes with it, can't figure it out, either.

Comment: You'll get better answers with a simpler test case: http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/586b038cfbf6b56680985c96

Comment: TouchIdServiceInterface.self return type of TouchIdServiceInterface.Protocol, rather than TouchIdServiceInterface.Type.

Comment: What's usage of return type of `func serviceDependencies() -> [InjectableService.Type]`?

Comment: This is (yet another) variant of [Protocol doesn't conform to itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself) – `TouchIdServiceInterface.self` (the protocol type itself – which is of type `TouchIdServiceInterface.Protocol`, not `TouchIdServiceInterface.Type`) is not convertible to `InjectableService.Type` (a type that *conforms* to `InjectableService` – which `TouchIdServiceInterface` doesn't).

Comment: If you tell us exactly what the use case of `serviceDependencies()` is, we may be able to offer a solution/workaround.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple document:

> **Metatype Type**
>
> A metatype type refers to the type of any type, including class types,
>   structure types, enumeration types, and protocol types.
>
> The metatype of a class, structure, or enumeration type is the name of
>   that type followed by `.Type`. The metatype of a protocol type—not the
>   concrete type that conforms to the protocol at runtime—is the name of
>   that protocol followed by `.Protocol`. For example, the metatype of the
>   class type SomeClass is `SomeClass.Type` and the metatype of the
>   protocol SomeProtocol is `SomeProtocol.Protocol`.
>
> You can use the postfix `self` expression to access a type as a value.
>   For example, `SomeClass.self` returns SomeClass itself, not an instance
>   of SomeClass. And `SomeProtocol.self` returns SomeProtocol itself, not
>   an instance of a type that conforms to SomeProtocol at runtime.

If you want to return `[InjectableService.Type]`, you need to define classes of each protocol.

```
public protocol InjectableService
{}

public protocol ClientDependency
{
    func injectDependencies(dependencies: [InjectableService])
    func serviceDependencies() -> [InjectableService.Type]
}

public protocol TouchIdServiceInterface : InjectableService
{
    func biometricAuthenticate() -> Void
}

public protocol PasswordServiceInterface : InjectableService
{
    func passwordAuthenticate() -> Void
}

public class TouchIdService: TouchIdServiceInterface {
    public func biometricAuthenticate() -> Void { }
}

public class PasswordService: PasswordServiceInterface {
    public func passwordAuthenticate() -> Void { }
}


public class LoginController: ClientDependency
{
    private var services: [InjectableService]!

    public func injectDependencies(dependencies: [InjectableService]) {
        services = dependencies
    }

    public func serviceDependencies() -> [InjectableService.Type] {
        let ts: [InjectableService.Type] = [
            TouchIdService.self,
            PasswordService.self
        ]
        return ts
    }

}

let controller = LoginController()
let services = controller.serviceDependencies()
```

**UPDATED**

```
public protocol ClientDependency
{
    func injectDependencies(dependencies: [InjectableService])
    func serviceDependencies() -> [Any]
}
```

LoginController:

```
public func serviceDependencies() -> [Any] {
    let ts: [Any] = [
        TouchIdServiceInterface.self,
        TouchIdServiceInterface.self
    ]
    return ts
}
```

Testing:

```
let controller = LoginController()
let services = controller.serviceDependencies()
if let touchIdService = services.first as? TouchIdServiceInterface.Protocol {
    print(touchIdService)
}
```

Comment: Doing this will defeat the purpose of what I am trying to design. LoginController which is a ClientDependency should not return the actual class type/object just a protocol. I am decoupling these two things.

Comment: InjectableService.Type must be class type, even you try to force cast it from `TouchIdServiceInterface.self as! InjectableService.Type`, it wouldn't compile.

Comment: Sorry my bad, yes, it compiled but when you call the method, you will have a runtime error. Please see my updated answer if you want to use protocol instead of class.

Comment: yeah I guess I have to do something like what you mentioned with the update, this sucks.

This is where I miss objC runtime inspection methods

Comment: I still don't know what do you do with the return value of `serviceDependencies()` or what's the purpose of it?

Comment: Are you familiar with Dependency Injenction? ServiceDependencies is just a client (dependency) returning the services it needs. Then an injector will use that information, create the service object instances, and inject it into the Client via the other method injectDependencies.

Comment: The client returns protocols/interfaces instead of the classes themselves because it need not know the exact classes, simply the interfaces of the services it needs. This decouples that process and allows the dependency (client) to be truly separate from its services.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132144/discussion-between-bubuxu-and-aybaybay).